# Can I use UIImagePickerController without asking for location data permissions?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

Is it  possible to use the image picker without asking for Core Location permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's up to the user - if he has enabled photo geotagging in Settings, iOS will always ask for permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it. The photos\videos that you'll get from it are stripped from any geotagging data. If you whant that data, you'll need to build youre own picker with "low-level api" such as `AVFoundation` and `CoreMedia`. More than that - you don't need to ask permissions. The alert asking user for such permissions will be presented to the user by the system in such case and will not be presented in case you are using `UIImagePickerController`.